# Is it possible to use a different theme for just a section on the page?

Tags: theming

In Drupal 7, using a different theme on each page is easy, but what I could really use in this particular case is **2 themes on the same page**.

Let's say I want to use *Rubik* theme for all page sections (menu, etc.) **except** 'content' section, where I'd like to use *Stark* theme.

Is this possible at all? If it is, how?

Comment: No, you can only have one active theme for a single page build as far as I know

Comment: The only other way I can think of is take the css you like from both themes and merge them into a new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Clive and Cromian for your input. Guess its not possible to actually use 2 different themes on the same page.

The simplest solution I found is to use one theme, then add 2nd ones css using [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) function. Then hope 2 CSS don't interfere too much and it's good enough without HTML part of the theme.